# Past simple or present perfect

Tags: present-perfect

I don't understand, what did I buy?I paid 12 usd so I thought first it was the lathe but as  I **have received** a confirmation for a digital release ....I'm very surprised

I don't understand, what did I buy?I paid 12 usd so I thought first it was the lathe but as  I **received** a confirmation for a digital release ....I'm very surprised

What is the best tense for receive **present perfect** or past simple

I think present perfect is better if I want to emphasize my surprise

I am surprised now because I have received a confirmation for a digital release

Comment: The present perfect doesn't indicate surprise but it does connect the event to the present.  The tense indicates that the receipt of the digital release was recent:  **I have received...**

Comment: Can you clarify the situation this quote is about? I can't understand what's going on- lathes, digital releases, and $12 aren't things that make sense together.

Answer (score 1):

> **have received**

is the better of your two options since it clearly puts ""received"" before your "surprise".

Using simple past for both might be interpreted that your surprise was at receiving the confirmation, not the contents of the confirmation.